# How to Commit Changes into Version Editor Everytime I compile the Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Anyone knows that? Or say every hour of programming. That way I don't have to remember committing my work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a shotgun approach to version control, just turn on Time Machine, or Snapshots in Xcode. (Don't know if that works automagically, but Time Machine does.

Doing what you are proposing defeats the point of having and using version control in the first place.

Comment: Okay maybe not every time I compile. Say once a day.